# ngSwitch and ngIf flicker in Angularjs 1.2.0-rc1

Tags: angularjs

Recently migrated to 1.2.0-rc1 and really happy with it. Especially for the `ngIf` which can be a big performance improvement for rendering, compared to `ngShow`.
Except there is some flickering when the boolean changes. See the plunkr below for an example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/iYMm0IHZkrRamlaEs9yD?p=preview

On Chrome (v28), you'll see that the first 2 implementations will flicker whereas the 2 others won't. 
On Firefox, the flicker happens only rarely.

Is that normal? Is there a way to avoid that? Should I go back to using `ngShow`?

**Edit:**
As sza said, ngIf and `ngSwitch` modify the DOM, whereas `ngShow` uses a css rule to display/hide elements. In angular 1.0.7, `ngSwitch` existed already and was already modifying the DOM and was great as we used it a lot in place of `ngShow` to avoid expensive rendering of things that were not displayed.
Now if you look at http://plnkr.co/edit/pIpEYZ5K8xvfd9dhAC74?p=preview, you'll see that there is no flickering with ngSwitch from 1.0.7.

The answer I'm expecting would be something like "this is normal behaviour, you're using `ngSwitch` and `ngIf` where they shouldn't be used, only static content should be displayed with `ngSwitch` and `ngIf`" or "this is a rendering bug, live with it until it is fixed". Of course a workaround would be nice too (@timp, I've seen your answer but I'm afraid I'd need a working example).

Comment: It almost appears as though ng-if's are evaluated independently but ng-show/ng-hides are pooled together and evaluated at the same time... would like to know more on this!

Comment: It seems people here are really on the cutting-edge...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the same question on the google group, and the answer was that it is a bug in the animation module:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/Fy-rVdXh5WQ/aqhppEl8Nw0J

Removing the dependency on the animation module will fix the flicker.

Comment: Has been fixed from rc2.

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the source code, you will see both `ngIf` and `ngSwitch` are all related to DOM manipulation, while `ngShowHide` only manipulates the CSS rather than DOM.

I guess the DOM manipulation will be a slightly more expensive than CSS change in terms of reflow and it may differ in different browsers.

Comment: The ng-switch from 1.0.7 doesn't flicker by the way, so this feels like a regression to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you try the ngIf demo on the AngularJS documentation page ([link](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf)), it has the same issue you described when the checkbox is toggled quickly.

If the improvement in rendering is important, try replacing the `checked` with two booleans. This way you can specify the order of which ngIf is evaluated first. It's a pain but it does the job.

Comment: For the solution you suggest I'd need an example, I'm not sure to understand.